# How to access Parsecs Input Stream directly

Tags: haskell, parsec

I want to access parsecs input stream directly which can be done using `getParserState`. To read from the stream the `uncons` method is provided. However I'm facing (as usual) a type related problem. so this is my parsing function:

```
myParser :: (Stream s m Char) => ParsecT s (ShiftedState u s) m String
myParser = do
  s <- P.getParserState
  let i = stateInput s
  let x = uncons i
  return ""
```

and I'm getting the following error.

```
Could not deduce (Stream s m0 Char)
        arising from a use of ‘uncons’
```

And the problem is simply that I do not quite know what exactly the error means. I think `uncons` runs in the underlying monad, not in the ParsecT monad. But I don't know how to lift (?) it.

Basically I would like to know how I can use `uncons` and read from the stream. Now please don't worry about wether one *should* do this... this is basically me understanding how monads work xD

Comment: Here’s what’s happening: `uncons` needs to run in some sort of monad (have a look at [the definition](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.14.0/docs/Text-Parsec.html#v:uncons)). But you’re just doing `let x = uncons i` — so `x` is a monadic computation returning the result of the `uncons`, but you haven’t specified _which_ monad this monadic computation is running within. The error just says that since you haven’t specified the monad, which it calls `m0`, GHC doesn’t necessarily know whether the monad `m0` is in fact an instance of `Stream s m0 Char`.

Comment: (The reason I didn’t post that as an answer was because I didn’t have a solution yet. But I think I do have one now — I’m reposting that comment as an answer now.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here’s what’s happening: `uncons` needs to run in some sort of monad. You can see this by its type signature: `uncons :: Stream s m t => s -> m (Maybe (t, s))`. But you’re just doing `let x = uncons i` — so `x` is a monadic computation which returns the result of `uncons i`, but you haven’t specified *which* monad this monadic computation is running within. *You* happen to know that you ‘want’ `uncons i` to run within your monad `m` (which satisfies `Stream s m Char`), but GHC doesn’t know this. So GHC makes the assumption that here, `uncons i :: m0 (Maybe (t, s))`, where `m0` is some arbitrary monad. Thus GHC produces the error you see, since `uncons` requires the constraint `Stream s m0 Char` to be satisfied in order to use it, yet that constraint isn’t necessarily satisfied for any random `m0`.

How can this be solved? Well, you already know that this whole computation is of type `ParsecT s (ShiftedState u s) m Char`, and `m` satisfies the instance `Stream s m Char`. And as it turns out, there is a function [`lift :: Monad m => m a -> ParsecT s u m a`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.14.0/docs/Text-Parsec.html#v:lift) which ‘lifts’ a monadic computation `m a` to a Parsec computation `ParsecT s u m a`. So you can just rewrite your function to:

```hs
myParser :: (Stream s m Char) => ParsecT s (ShiftedState u s) m String
myParser = do
  s <- P.getParserState
  let i = stateInput s
  x <- lift (uncons i)
  return ""
```

I haven’t tested it, but this should work if I haven’t made any mistakes.

(Another solution is to simply give `x` a type signature:

```hs
let x :: m (Maybe (Char, s))
    x = uncons i
```

This forces `x` to have the type you want. Now GHC can look and see that `m` and `s` all satisfy the relevant constraint, so does not produce that error. But this requires the `ScopedTypeVariables` language extension to compile, and is much less elegant than the previous solution.)